# Overwriting content Issue in IE

Tags: php, html, jquery

This is my code. In Mozilla the `add_PM` div will be overwritten by the content of the variable `msg`. But in IE the variable `msg` has content but the `add_PM` div is not overwritten so nothing will be displayed. Is there is any problem in my code?

```
function addPjctMngr(){
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/addProjectManager",
    success: function(msg){
      $("#add_PM").html(msg).show();
    }  
  });
}
```

When I tried to use this code

```
$("#add_PM").html('');
$("#add_PM").html(msg).show();
```

Nothing happens in IE.

Comment: why not using: `url: "/index.php/admin/addProjectManager"`?
`

Comment: it is a codeigniter application so this is the complete url path to controller url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/addProjectManager"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#add_PM").html('');
$("#add_PM").html(msg).show();
```

Hope  it  helps

Comment: Nothing will happend.nothing will displayed